# iPhone XML parser wont add object to mutable array

Tags: iphone

Greetings,

I have a problem with adding an object from parser to mutable array.
It was working fine until I moved MtableArray from AppDelegate to ViewController. This is where I call parser (MutableArray is inside this View also):

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://example.com"];
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

 parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

 [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

 [xmlParser parse];
```

...and this is inside parser where objects should be added:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Element"]) {

  [viewController.marray addObject:parsedObj];

  [parsedObj release];
  parsedObj = nil;
  }
```

marray is synthesized inside viewController. Parser is doing good job, I tried with NSLog, but marray.count is always (null). Please help!!!

Comment: hav u tried by commenting [parsedObj release]?

Comment: agreed, if parseObj is already autoreleased, then you are reducing the retain count enough to effectively remove its reference in the mutable array

Comment: If the parsedObjects were over-released then accessing the contents of the array would result in a bad access exception, but the array count wouldn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

[viewController.marray addObject:[parsedObj copy]];

Comment: Copying the objects as they are inserted into the array won't change anything about the array's count, which is the stated problem.

Comment: No, problem is that array count is always null, it should be counting number of objects inside. This means that it is always empty. I think I did something wrong in accessing this marray... I posted some more code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the marray property is non-nil?  If it somehow hasn't been set properly then all of the insertions will be no-ops, and the the result of the count method will be nil.

Now that you've posted more code, this line is your problem:

```
[marray init];
```

You need to alloc/init a new NSMutableArray; this line is simply sending the init message to nil.

Comment: I posted some more code that contains everything needed to understand the problem. NSMutableArray is empty in the beggining and I want to fill it using parser.

Comment: you want something like `marray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];` not simply [marray init]

Comment: But I synhesize marray and it is also initiated in XMLparser.m

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more code?

If you are inside view controller when marray is being called, you shouldn't have to call `viewController.marray`, just `marray`

One suggestion, from my experience in parsing, is to use an NSMutableDictionary instead of an array..so, for instance:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    currentElement = [elementName copy];

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    //Clear out story item caches
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentAddress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentCity = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentState = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentZip = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentId = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```

}

and then to add everything:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    //Save values to an item, then store that item into the array
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentAddress forKey:@"address"];
    [item setObject:currentCity forKey:@"city"];
    [item setObject:currentState forKey:@"state"];
    [item setObject:currentZip forKey:@"zip"];
    [item setObject:currentId forKey:@"id"];

           // venues is the mutable array
    [venues addObject:[item copy]];
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Now my mutable array has all the elements I need, and I can do various things with it (like reload a table cell). The above code has been tested and verified as working.

Comment: When you are doing [parsedObj setValue:cValue forKey:elementName]; I think you should try changing it to:  [parsedObj setObject:cValue forKey:@"elementName"]; I don't really understand what parsedObj is doing though...that might be part of the problem...My suggestion would be to instantiate an NSMutableDictionary object instead..In most cases like this, I would say 'try out my (working) code' and see what success you have with that...

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same thing. My parsed object holds info from xml. So, it has strings named same as xml elements and I add value to them. That part is working ok...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more code:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class XMLParser;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    NSMutableArray *marray;

    XMLParser *parser;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *marray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) XMLParser *parser;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#

import "ViewController.h"
    #import "ParsedObj.h"
    #import "XMLParser.h"

    @synthesize marray;
    @synthesize parser;

(...)

    -(void)search:(id)sender{

        [marray init];

         NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://example.com"];


    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

     parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

     [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

     [xmlParser parse];

(...)

    @end
```

XMLparser.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController, ParsedObj;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

    ViewController *viewController;
    ParsedObj *parsedObj;

}

@end
```

..and XMLparser.m:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ParsedObj.h"

@implementation XMLParser

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Root"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        viewController.marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Element"]) {

        //Initialize the hotel.
        parsedObj = [[ParsedObj alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        parsedObj.ID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Root"])
        return;

    //There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
    //If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
    // and release the object.
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Element"]) {

        [accomodationController.marray addObject:parsedObj];

        parsedObj = nil;
    }
    else {
        NSString *cValue=[currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [parsedObj setValue:cValue forKey:elementName];
    }

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [parsedObj release];
    [currentElementValue release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach and now I have two solutions and a problem with both of them.
I have a XML parser that should add objects to NSMutableArray from where it has been called at first. Parser is working OK, but here is the problem.
First approach:

I changed NSXMLParser's init method inside my XMLParser.m (mArray is for Mutable Array and):

```
- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser:(id)sender {
 [super init];
 mArray=(NSMutableArray *)sender; 
 return self;}
```

mArray in implementation file XMLParser.h:

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
 NSMutableString *currentElementValue; 
 NSMutableArray *mArray;
 Object *aObject;}
-(XMLParser *) initXMLParser:(id)sender;
@end
```

So, let's get to the part where we call XMLParser from ViewController.m:

```
    mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.a.com/some.xml"];
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser:self.mArray];
 [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    [xmlParser parse];
```

...and here is ViewController.h:

```
    @class XMLParser;
    @interface AccomodationSecondViewController : UIViewController{ 
    @public NSMutableArray *mArray;}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mArray;
```

I'm not sure because this is first time I'm using public objects so...
Anyway, this is the part inside XMLParser.m that should add objects:

```
    //This is for closing bracket
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Element"]) {    
     [mArray addObject:aObject];
     [aObject release];
     aObject=nil;}
```

So, the idea is to make mutable array mArray public inside ViewController and to send pointer to it to XMLParser. I know that this may be little unnatural, but I just want to get it to work.

My other idea is this:
To send pointer of ViewController to XMLParser and do the rest. So, I changed initXMLParser:

```
- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser:(id)sender {
    [super init];
    viewController=(ViewController *)sender;    
    return self;}
```

and this is the part inside ViewController.m where I call my method:

```
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser:self];
```

then I add object:

```
[viewController.mArray addObject:aObject];
```

Why is this not working??!!